# How can I run a console command in Gradle upon build?

Tags: java, linux, windows, gradle, rust

I'm currently working on a project that has a native component in Rust and a Java component. The main build system is Gradle, and I want Gradle to invoke the Rust build system (Cargo) upon build, every time, to ensure that the proper shared libraries exist for JNI to take place, and for those libraries to be recompiled as needed. After research, I came up with this:

```
task buildRustDebug(type:Exec){
    workingDir './native'
    commandLine 'cargo', 'build'
}

task buildRustRelease(type:Exec){
    workingDir './native'
    commandLine 'cargo', 'build', '--release'
}

task buildRust(){
    dependsOn 'buildRustDebug'
    dependsOn 'buildRustRelease'
}

build dependsOn 'buildRust'
```

This all works fine, except for the last line that establishes a dependency with the `build` task. This line, when present, gives the following error when I attempt to run *any* task:

```
Build file '<censored>' line: 23

A problem occurred evaluating root project '<censored>'.
> Could not get unknown property 'dependsOn' for root project '<censored>' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

It looks like somehow the `build` task doesn't exist until after the code in my main file runs. How can I accomplish what I want? Note that this code is in the root project of a multi-project Gradle build.

Comment: I've never used gradle, but a quick search suggests the syntax is probably `build.dependsOn ...`, assuming `build` is a name of a task

Comment: @AlexLarionov See my response to Bjørn's answer. That solution doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment you got on the question is correct. But just to give you some context (and make it possible to mark the question as solved):

Gradle uses either Groovy or Kotlin for the scripting language. You are using Groovy.

When you write `dependsOn 'buildRustDebug'`, you are calling a method called [dependsOn](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#dependsOn-java.lang.Object...-) with the String argument `'buildRustDebug'`. This works because in Groovy, [method parenthesis are optional](http://www.groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses). So it is the same as `dependsOn('buildRustDebug')`.

When you write `build dependsOn 'buildRust'`, it is syntactically incorrect. You want to call the `dependsOn` method on the `build` object with an argument. Try this instead:

```
build.dependsOn 'buildRust' // Or
build.dependsOn('buildRust')
```

Notice the dot before the method call.

Another thing is that `build` is one of the "outermost" tasks in the dependency trees, and it itself depends on other tasks like `compileJava` and `test`. If you want to make sure your Rust project is built and available before assembling your application or testing it, you probably need to move the dependency down the tree a bit. Otherwise you risk that the `buildRust` task is the very last thing it does, whereas it should probably be one of the *first* things it does.

Comment: I tried adding both `compileJava.dependsOn('buildRust')` and `build.dependsOn('buildRust')`, and in both cases, I get an error like this: `A problem occurred evaluating root project '<censored>'.
> Could not get unknown property 'compileJava' for root project '<censored>' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
`. (I did try the dot access operator before posting originally.)

Comment: I just tried it in a small example project, and it works fine. So something else is going on that you are not showing in the build.gradle file. But this is the correct syntax. Maybe you are not applying any plugins in this project where you want to depend on the rust build? By default there are no tasks in a Gradle project - not even a `build` task. These come from plugins. If this is the case, and you like to have a task named `build`, you can apply the [base](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/base_plugin.html) plugin.

Comment: ...but to get a dependency to tasks like `compileJava`, it of cause has to be a Java project with the `java` plugin applied.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be a no-plugin issue. I'd like to switch my vote on your answer, but I can't do so unless you edit it. I think that adding the plugin issue to the answer body would be a worthy addition.